# property about truth tables

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Is the question "show that any truth table is same as the truth table for some wff built from $\neg,\implies,\iff$ only"

the same as asking show that any wff is logically equivalent to some wff built from $\neg,\implies,\iff$ only?

Comment: Yes, they are equivalent assertions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are equivalent assertions.

If you already know that any truth table is the same as the truth table of some wff built using $\land$, $\lor$, and $\lnot$, then all you need is to show that $\land$ and $\lor$ can be simulated using $\lnot$ and $\implies$.

It is not hard to do $\lor$. Since the truth table of $a\implies b$ is the same as the truth table of $\lnot a \lor b$, the truth table of $\lnot a\implies b$ is the same as the truth table of $a\lor b$. We leave dealing with $\land$ to you.